# awk/sed/grep command to compare the contents of three files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

Hi I am trying to automate some data entry, and I am using a tcp server/client to send filenames around for other server to go into a repository and pull these files. as part of testing this I am running the program with logging the filenames that are supposed to be sent, what was received, and if it got received I am sending a reply back with the filename.

so I have three text files with file names inside of them.

```
SupposedToSend.txt
Recieved.txt
GotReplyFor.txt
```

I know that awk could do what I am trying to do but I am not sure how to set it up, I need to compare the three files for elements that does not exists in any of the other files, so if one entry is missing from any file i need to know which one and from which file.

I can write a program for this which will take much longer to write and to run since these files are getting 5 elements/minute dumped into them

Comment: 5 elements per minute is not very fast. Do you want a tool that searches for odd filenames *once*, or *every few seconds*?

Comment: only once, I want to run it for a couple of hours and make sure that the file name's are being sent without issues that's why I am checking at these three points... so I only need to run it once and get the names that do not exist in the other two files

Comment: You can use `awk` but it would be easier to do in Perl.  You basically want to save each line into an associate array (or hash in perl), and then compare arrays (hashes).

Comment: How about running `diff` 3 times and getting the information you need that way? If you are only running once, this might be the fastest way.

Comment: so you mean diff fileA fileB, diff fileA fileC, diff fileB fileC???

Comment: I just noticed a contradiction in the question. Do you want the tool to report every file name that appears in one list but a) not in **any** of the others, or b) not in **all** of the others? That is, if a file name appears in two of the three, should the tool report it?

Comment: You need to show samples the actual contents of the three files, and explain in detail what you want.  The question as it stands is open to many interpretations and is essentially not answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
paste -d '\n' SupposedToSend.txt Recieved.txt GotReplyFor.txt | uniq -c | grep -v '^   3'
```

It's tolerable if you have no errors, deeply suboptimal otherwise.  Or if the data in the different files is out of sequence...  (In which case you might need to ***sort*** them somehow.)

Or you could just run ***diff3*** to compare 3 files...

Comment: the first one cat worked fine ill try paste and see the difference.. thanks!!